# How to programmatically change an SVG symbol in the Vector Layer?

Tags: qgis, python, symbology, svg

I'm trying to change the symbol used in a layer via Python. I've been able to tunnel through a vector layer to the symbol layer, but I don't know how to change the symbol it's using. I'd like to update it using a filename.

Here's what I have so far:

```
qgis.console.clearConsole()
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

r = layer.rendererV2()
sym = r.symbols()[0]

symLayer = sym.symbolLayer(0)
```

symLayer seems like it should have what I'm looking for, but I haven't found it yet.

Is this even possible?